# JQUERY MOBILE clone form with select, and reset options

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I'm trying to clone a form that is based on jquery mobile design.
The problem is when the select is cloned, because I can not select other options.
Please check the code at https://jsfiddle.net/vgacia24/1jmxjzya/5/

here is the code

```js
$(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length, // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        newNum = new Number(num + 1), // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
        newElem = $('#testingDiv' + num).clone().attr('id', 'testingDiv' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');// Crea un nuevo elemento usando "clone()", y manipula el ID usando el valor "newNum"
       
        // TEXTO DIVISOR
        newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('INGREDIENTE ' + newNum);

       
        // LISTA 2
        newElem.find('.test-select-label2').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_select');
        newElem.find('.test-select2').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_select').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_select').val('');

        // Insert el nuevo elemento despues del ultimo campo "input" duplicado
        $('#testingDiv' + num).after(newElem);

         // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

        // Cantidad limite de formularios que se puede agregar, Por ahora tiene un limite de 10
        if (newNum == 10) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "Limite de Formulario Alcanzado");
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        // EN EL SISTEMA NO SE ESTA USANDO LA OPCION DE ELIMINAR
        if (confirm("¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar el ULTIMO ingrediente agregado?")) { 
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
            // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            $('#testingDiv' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num - 1 === 1) $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "[ + ] add to this form");
            });
        }
        return false;
        // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="testingDiv1" class="clonedInput" >
                                <h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">INGREDIENTE</h2>
                            
                                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                                   <form>
                                                            <select  name="unidad" id="unidad" class="test-select2" data-native-menu="true">
                                                                <option value="">Seleccionar Unidad</option>
                                                                <option value="kg">Kg</option>
                                                                <option value="lts">Lts</option>
                                                            </select> 
                                                         </form>
                                                    </li>
                                                
                            </ul>
                            <div id="add-del-buttons">
                                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-icon="false" data-divider-theme="b">
                                  
                                    <button type="button"   id="btnAdd" data-role="button" >Agregar Otro Ingrediente</button>
                                    <button type="button"   id="btnDel" data-role="button" >Eliminar Último Ingrediente</button>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                                <button type="submit"   id="guardarReceta" data-role="button" >Guardar</button>
                        </div>
</form>
```

Please check the code at jsfiddle link to try with jquery mobile 
https://jsfiddle.net/vgacia24/1jmxjzya/3/

Comment: Have you tried ours solutions ? Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: your solution worked to solve that problem. but you were right, you said "Please keep in mind it will be really difficult for you to maintain such code. You should find a way to do not use jQuery.clone()." so i changed my idea, and now im working with "autocomplete listview" and with "data filter" to solve my problem... thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery.clone() is a terrible idea here because jQueryMobile will modify your HTML to create some elements.

In our case it replace this :

```
<select name="unidad" id="unidad" class="test-select2" data-native-menu="true">
    <option value="">Seleccionar Unidad</option>
    <option value="kg">Kg</option>
    <option value="lts">Lts</option>
 </select>
```

By this :

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div id="unidad-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <span class="test-select2">Seleccionar Unidad</span>
        <select name="unidad" id="unidad" class="test-select2" data-native-menu="true">
            <option value="">Seleccionar Unidad</option>
            <option value="kg">Kg</option>
            <option value="lts">Lts</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

So your clone also copy the generated HTML from jQueryMobile. A quick dirty fix would be to manipulate this new HTML to remove useless stuff and ask jQueryMobile to apply again.

You can do so this way :

```
// LISTA 2
    newElem.find('.test-select-label2').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_select');
    var tmp = newElem.find('select').clone();
    newElem.find('.ui-select').before(tmp).remove();
    newElem.find('.test-select2').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_select').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_select').val('').selectmenu();
```

**Please keep in mind it will be really difficult for you to maintain such code**. You should find a way to do not use jQuery.clone().

Here is the jsFiddle ;) : https://jsfiddle.net/1jmxjzya/4/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a template engine (like [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) instead of cloning.

UPDATE:

Example using Handlebars:

Template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="testingDiv{{num}}" class="clonedInput" >
            <h2 id="ID_{{num}}_reference" name="ID_{{num}}_reference" class="heading-reference">INGREDIENTE {{num}}</h2>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <form>
                    <select  name="unidad" id="ID_{{num}}_select" class="test-select2" data-native-menu="true">
                        <option value="">Seleccionar Unidad</option>
                        <option value="kg">Kg</option>
                        <option value="lts">Lts</option>
                    </select> 
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var html = $("#template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(html);
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length + 1, // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        newElem = template({num: num});
        // Insert el nuevo elemento despues del ultimo campo "input" duplicado
        $('#add-del-buttons').before(newElem);
        // Enhance inserted element
        $("#testingDiv" + num).listview().enhanceWithin();
...
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/vo598s18/